Why does pinch-off occur in a MOSFET?
Considering an n-channel MOSFET with the source and the substrate at the same potential and the drain at a higher potential, although the potential difference across the oxide layer decreases along the direction from the source to the drain, the potential difference across the depletion layer increases along this direction. Why doesn't the latter create an inversion layer so that pinch-off doesn't occur when the drain potential is increased?

What depletion layer are you referring to?

That formed in the substrate under the oxide when a potential higher than that applied to the substrate is applied to the gate.
